# Graffiti onto mesh with multiple UVs

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am trying to find a way to paint graffiti onto this object with multiple meshes where each one has its own UV and its own image texture.

The graffiti I want to paint is originally a PNG image.
Ideally, I could turn this PNG image into some type of stamp or brush, and use Texture Paint to add it to everything. Would that be the easiest way?

Or, what would be the easiest way to do this?

The blend file is shared here, [train_sketchfab.blend](https://we.tl/t-nh7WZTPghb).

[image: Screenshot of train]

Comment: Use for this stamp image object coordinates or another UV from View ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add graffiti image and control position and scale by another object like an Empty used for Texture Coordinate node > Object ...

[image]
[image]

To use it in more materials you would have to add those nodes into each material. Close these nodes into a node Group to easier add them into materials and sync control between materials for later adjustments (if needed).

[image]
[image]

Note: instead of texture coordinates from object, you can use another UV Map ... just add another UV slot in Data Properties, Unwrapp > Project from View.

To use image as Brush (Stamp) it is possible, but I don't think blender can paint across several textures at the same time.
Maybe if set as UDIM?